# passing xml nodes/documents/fragments as parameters to xslt

Tags: java, xalan

I tried to pass a `w3c.dom.Document`, `Element` and `NodeList` as parameters to a xslt transform.

I want to be able to process it within the xslt:

```xml
<xsl:param name="links" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <record>
        <xsl:for-each select="$links/*">
            <test />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </record>
</xsl:template>
```

I pass the parameter as:

```
        Document params = createLinksParams(links);
        transformer.setParameter("links", params);
```

I get this exception:

> 'Invalid conversion from 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl' to 'node-set'.'

I tried also `exslt:node-set()`, `xalan:nodeset()` etc, but it doesn't work.

It seems that internally xalan excepts his own implementation of the Node.

How can I do something similar without incurring in this problem?

I cannot use `document($param)` because I construct the doc on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Posting a new answer, as the previous one did not solve the issue and this new one is radically different from the previous)*

Seems to be a known issue with XALAN compiling processor ( [XALANJ-2057](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2057),
[How can I pass a node as parameter to translets for XSLTC Processor](https://marc.info/?l=xalan-j-users&m=116982111306829&w=2)).

So, what are the alternatives?

1. **mess around with URIs** as outlined in
   a response to [How can I pass a node
   as parameter to translets for XSLTC
   Processor](https://marc.info/?l=xalan-j-users&m=116982111306829&w=2) post
2. Instead of
   XALAN compiling processor (XSLTC),
   **use XALAN interpretive processor**. Or any other XSLT processor that supports such behavior.
3. **Use DTMAxisIterator**
   instead, also outlined in a response to [How can I pass a node
   as parameter to translets for XSLTC
   Processor](https://marc.info/?l=xalan-j-users&m=117007764209577&w=2) post - not sure if it will work, though.
4. **Create a new DOM tree**, combining your "parameter" DOM and the original XSLT input document

Comment: Solution 3 doesn't seem to work when the node to be passed as param comes from a DOM document which is not the document being transformed.

Comment: Some links are dead

Comment: Fixed the links

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution (here: [XSLT Processing with Java : passing xml content in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110750/xslt-processing-with-java-passing-xml-content-in-parameter))  which may work for your case as well:

```
String urls = "<urls><url id='google'>https://www.google.com</url>...";
trans.setParameter("lookupdoc", new StreamSource(new StringReader(urls)));
```

instead of creating a uriresolver from a string, just create a stream source from a string reader and pass it to the stylesheet.

After that, I was able to access the doc normally as XML:

```
<xsl:param name="lookupdoc"><urls/></xsl:param> 
... 
<xsl:variable name="googleurl" select="$lookupdoc/@id='google"/>
```

Did not test with xalan, but maybe the answer will help others who stumble onto this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example with the URIResolver Gambit, #1 in the list of solutions:

```java
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.URIResolver;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class XSLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        class MyResolver implements URIResolver {
            String _xml;
            MyResolver(String xml) { _xml = xml; }
            @Override
            public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
                return new StreamSource(new StringReader(_xml));
            }
        }

        String lookup =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n" +
            "<urls>\n" +
            "    <url id='google'>https://www.google.com</url>\n" +
            "    <url id='yahoo'>https://www.yahoo.com</url>\n" +
            "    <url id='apple'>https://www.apple.com</url>\n" +
            "</urls>";

        String main =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>" +
            "<list>"+
            "   <link ref='yahoo'>Yahoo</link>"+
            "   <link ref='google'>Google</link>"+
            "</list>";

        String xsl =
            "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" +
            "<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>\n" +
            "    <xsl:param name='lookup-doc' />\n" +
            "    <xsl:variable name='lookup' select='document($lookup-doc)'/>\n" +
            "    <xsl:template match='/'>\n" +
            "        <xsl:for-each select='//link'>\n" +
            "            <xsl:variable name='ref' select='@ref'/>\n" +
            "            <xsl:element name='a'>\n" +
            "                <xsl:attribute name='href'>\n" +
            "                    <xsl:value-of select='$lookup//url[@id=$ref]'/>\n" +
            "                </xsl:attribute>\n" +
            "                <xsl:value-of select='text()'/>\n" +
            "            </xsl:element>\n" +
            "        </xsl:for-each>\n" +
            "    </xsl:template>\n" +
            "</xsl:stylesheet>";

        try {

            // xsl doc
            Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsl));

            TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);

            // main doc
            Source mainSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(main));

            // lookup doc - stage it in the URI resolver
            trans.setURIResolver(new MyResolver(lookup));
            // dummy URL, you could use different values here to 
            // support multiple document parameters
            trans.setParameter("lookup-doc", "xml://lookup");

            StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
            trans.transform(mainSource, new StreamResult(out));

            System.out.println(out.toString());

        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            System.err.println("It's the wrong trousers Gromit, and they've gone wrong!");
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }
}
```

I also had a working version where I put the xml source **in** the URI like

```
xml://<urls><url><url id='google'>https://www.google.com</url>...
```

but I figured that might run into length limits somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Document JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), you can see that it extends [Node](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) interface, but not [NodeList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html). Not sure if it will work, but you could try to pass in *params.getChildNodes()* instead of *params*.

Comment: Maybe it is related to this bug? http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=5059947

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest to take the stacktrace of that error and track down in Xalan source code the specific circumstance when this exception is thrown.

Comment: Yes, before posting here I checked the sources:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid conversion from 'com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl' to 'node-set'.
 at    com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.BasisLibrary.runTimeError(BasisLibrary.java:1523)
 at   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.BasisLibrary.runTimeError(BasisLibrary.java:1531)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.BasisLibrary.referenceToNodeSet(BasisLibrary.java:999)

Comment: method "referenceToNodeSet" accepts only "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.Node" instances, which are wrappers to dom nodes. There is a helper used to create those wrappers, in BasisLibrary, which requires a "Translet" instance as a mandatory parameter. The translet instance has to be taken from a protected member of the TransformerImpl instance. Unfortunately the jar is sealed and I get a access exception trying to access that protected getter.

Comment: I'm also interested in alternative approaches to my problem. For now I will quickly hack my solution by wrapping the input document together with my parameter class "<package><params>...</params><originaldoc</package>". But I don't really like this kind of hacks. Other ideas would be to create a custom url protocol and use 'select="document('mydummyprotocol:somekey')' and hook 'somekey' to my generated xml. Also this sounds too hackish.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue with XALAN compiling processor ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2057, http://old.nabble.com/How-can-I-pass-a-node-as-parameter-to-translets-for-XSLTC-Processor-td8649149.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's an annoyance, one way or the other. In the end, I've always found it easiest and most compatible with other XSLT processors to serialize the XML fragment to a temp file, pass that file's URI to XSLT as a string parameter, and from there load the URI via the XPath document() function.