# XSLT Processing with Java : passing xml content in parameter

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I would like to pass a parameter containing *XML* content when processing *XSLT*.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.xml.transform.Result; 
import javax.xml.transform.Source; 
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer; 
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException; 
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult; 
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource; 

File xmlFile = new File(xmlFilePath);
File xsltFile = new File(xslFilePath);
Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(xmlFile);
Result result = new StreamResult(System.out);

TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
trans.setParameter("foo", "<bar>Hello1</bar><bar>Hello2</bar>");
trans.transform(xmlSource, result);
```

Then I'd like to select the values contained in the 'bar' tag in my XSL file.

```
<xsl:param name="foo"/>
...
<xsl:value-of select="$foo//foo[1]" />
```

But this doesn't work, I get this error message:

```
org.apache.xpath.objects.XString cannot be cast to org.apache.xpath.objects.XNodeSet
```

So I guess I should pass an XML object to my setParameter method, but which one?
I can't find a simple example how to create an XNodeSet object...

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you strip the tags before passing the parameter??

Comment: You need to produce a *parsed* XML document and then pass this as the value of the parameter -- not the *string* you are now passing. Read your XSLT processor documentation how passing of parameters of type XMLDocument is supported.

Comment: @Marc Maybe you should update your question to reflect how you want to process this parameter - since you dont want to just display it...

Comment: @quaylar: ok done sorry my first post was confused.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Saxon, the simplest solution is to pass a StreamSource as the parameter value:

```
setParameter("foo", new StreamSource(new StringReader("<bar>baz</bar>")));
```

But this might not work with other processors: JAXP leaves it implementation-defined what kinds of Object can be passed as parameter values.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the documentation of your XSLT processor what kind of parameter types it allows and whether and how it allows to pass in a node and not a string. If I understand http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html and  http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/jaxp/TransformerImpl.html#setParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object) correctly then Saxon allows you to pass in nodes in the form of its `NodeInfo`.

Comment: Ok thanks will have a look at it because I'd like to pass xml so that I'll be able to select nodes in the XSL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xalan (the built-in implementation in the Java JDK), then pass a "URI" as the parameter value, which is any value you wish that is mapped in the subsequent step:

```kotlin
setParameter("foo", "myxml")
```

Now, define a `URIResolver` on the transformer (example in Kotlin, but the java translation is straightforward):

```kotlin
val transformer = factory.newTransformer(...)
transformer.setURIResolver { href, base ->
  when (href) {
    "myxml" -> StreamSource(StringReader("<bar>baz</bar>"))
    else -> error("Cannot resolve href $href")
  }
}
```

Define as many URIs and mappings to `Source`'s as necessary.

In the stylesheet, use the `document` function to pass the URI String parameter to the custom `URIResolver` and transform it into an XML document:

```xml
  <xsl:param name="foo" />
  <xsl:param name="fooDoc" select="document($foo)" />
```