# XSL deleting specific nodes and adding new adding a new node

Tags: xml, xslt

I wish to delete few nodes in an xml and add new a node. Let me illustrate with the following xml:

```
<resprocessing>
  <respcondition title="Correct" continue="No">
    <conditionvar>
      <varequal respident="Response_0">
        <nhm_blank_name>Answer:</nhm_blank_name>
        <nhm_numerator>14</nhm_numerator>
        <nhm_denominator>25</nhm_denominator>
        <nhm_allow_multiples>No</nhm_allow_multiples>
      </varequal>
    </conditionvar>
  </respcondition>
</resprocessing>
```

I want to remove the nodes `<nhm_numerator>` and `<nhm_denominator>` and insert a new node(`<nhm_blank_value>`) under `<varequal>`while retaining the other two nodes  `<nhm_blank_name>` `<nhm_allow_multiples>`

The new node has a value like this:

```
<nhm_blank_value>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mfrac>
    <mn>14</mn>
    <mn>25</mn>
  </mfrac>
</math>
</nhm_blank_value>
```

I used the following XSLT to successfully delete the aforementioned nodes. But i couldn't add the new node. Please tell me where I m going wrong

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="mathml">
  <nhm_blank_value>
    <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <mfrac>
        <mn>14</mn>
        <mn>25</mn>
      </mfrac>
    </math>
  </nhm_blank_value>
 </xsl:param>
<!-- copy the xml as it is -->   
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   <!-- deleting nodes numerator and denominator -->
   <xsl:template  match="questestinterop/item/resprocessing/respcondition/conditionvar/varequal/nhm_denominator" />
   <xsl:template    match="questestinterop/item/resprocessing/respcondition/conditionvar/varequal/nhm_numerator" />   
   <!-- adding mathml node -->
   <xsl:template match="questestinterop/item/resprocessing/respcondition/conditionvar">
     <xsl:value-of select="varequal">
       <xsl:with-param name="mathml"/>
     </xsl:value-of>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <!-- copy the xml as it is -->   
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- delete denominator -->
  <xsl:template  match="nhm_denominator" />

  <!-- replace numerator with mathml fragment -->
  <xsl:template match="nhm_numerator">
    <nhm_blank_value>
      <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
        <mfrac>
          <mn><xsl:value-of select="." /></mn>
          <mn><xsl:value-of select="../nhm_denominator"/></mn>
        </mfrac>
      </math>
    </nhm_blank_value>
  </xsl:template>   

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will pull the right numerator and denominator values from the original XML rather than hard-coding 14 and 25.  When run on your sample XML it produces the correct output:

```
<resprocessing>
  <respcondition title="Correct" continue="No">
    <conditionvar>
      <varequal respident="Response_0">
        <nhm_blank_name>Answer:</nhm_blank_name>
        <nhm_blank_value>
          <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
            <mfrac>
              <mn>14</mn>
              <mn>25</mn>
            </mfrac>
          </math>
        </nhm_blank_value>
        <nhm_allow_multiples>No</nhm_allow_multiples>
      </varequal>
    </conditionvar>
  </respcondition>
</resprocessing>
```

Comment: Thats awesome. But can I add pass param value while replacing the numerator node? Because this param value will be populated from a java program.

Comment: @jaykumarark do you mean a parameter containing the whole replacement fragment or just the numerator/denominator values?

Comment: I mean the parameter containing the fragment. The param will receive the mathml value from a java program. I want to place the param value under the `<varequal>` node

Comment: @jaykumarark the answer depends on which XSLT processor you're using, different processors have different ways to pass in a parameter that is a node set.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9113567/592139) shows how to do it with Saxon, other processors may be different.  Once you do have a suitable parameter value then it's a simple case of `<xsl:template match="nhm_numerator"><xsl:copy-of select="$theParameter" /></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I can pass parameters. But Im talking using them in the xslt. Is this syntax correct? `<!-- adding mathml node -->
   <xsl:template match="nhm_numerator">
       <xsl:value-of select="$mathml" />
   </xsl:template>` But when I do this, it is evaluating the mathml and placing the values directly. It is not placing the mathml nodes under that element.

Comment: @jaykumarark indeed - `copy-of` copies the nodes directly, whereas `value-of` gives you the string value of the node set (if it's a set of elements that means the concatenation of all the descendant text nodes of the first element in the node set).